# TCadmin editing default command lines

Tags: configuration, server

So i have had no luck piecing together the documentation on how to do this as it seems a bit scattered.

So i have a dedicated box running TCadmin. I have a cs go server deployed through it however now i have reached the stage of needing to add my GSLT.

I have looked through all the documentation and i have kind of got to the point of realising that i need to edit the default template of configuration that is used so that i can add a autoexec.cfg and allow that to be edited through the config editor. The other way would be to edit the default command line to allow +sv_setsteamaccount

I am totally stuck as to do either of these things though.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to nearly every other source on the internet, i CAN declare the login token in the server.cfg

The problem i was facing with the templating turned out to be simply a misunderstanding of the fact that the linux template was set up as a kind of "child" of the windows version as all the configs are the same. I had to amend the windows setup.